# <input> tags not rendering in Safari?

Tags: html, input, safari, mailchimp, newsletter

experiencing an  issue within a mailchimp embed form, wondered if anybody has come across this before?

Input tags are not rendering in the html markup in safari, but they are however for Chrome and Firefox. Have removed all custom CSS and used various naked embed codes but issue still persists.

Chrome - [markup in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmTd5.jpg)

Safari - [markup in safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzHdQ.jpg)

The embed code is as follows minus the bot form sign-up divs.

```html
<div id="mc_embed_signup">

<form action="https://tradingboundaries.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=e058d795d31f39e18b6c32f75&amp;id=ea8b3c7a1a" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

 <h2 class="h-custom-headline cs-ta-center h-resp-main mtn mbs h2 accent">
           <span><span style="font-size:0.6em;" class="h-sup">Newsletter</span></span>
        </h2>

<div class="mc-field-group">

    <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>

 <input type="email" placeholder="e.g. thelambliesdown@broadway.com " value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
  
</div>

<div class="mc-field-group input-group">

    <ul>
       <li><input class="regular-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="group[13][1]" id="mce-group[13]-13-0"><label for="mce-group[13]-13-0">Container Arrivals</label></li>

       <li><input class="regular-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" name="group[13][2]" id="mce-group[13]-13-1"><label for="mce-group[13]-13-1"> Gigs &
 Events</label></li>

       <li><input class="regular-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" name="group[13][4]" id="mce-group[13]-13-2"><label for="mce-group[13]-13-2">Latest TB News</label></li>

   </ul>

</div>

 <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
  
  <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
    
  <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    
 </div>  
  
  </div>

</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

notice you don't have a closing tag for your input or try add form-controls to your input class. hope this help.

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="https://tradingboundaries.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=e058d795d31f39e18b6c32f75&amp;id=ea8b3c7a1a" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
<h2 class="h-custom-headline cs-ta-center h-resp-main mtn mbs h2 accent">
<span><span style="font-size:0.6em;" class="h-sup">Newsletter</span></span>
 </h2>
<div class="mc-field-group">
<label for="mce-EMAIL">Email<span class="asterisk">*</span></label>
<input type="email" placeholder="e.g. thelambliesdown@broadway.com " value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" />  
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group input-group">
<ul>
<li><input class="regular-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" name="group[13][1]" id="mce-group[13]-13-0"><label for="mce-group[13]-13-0">Container Arrivals</label></li>
<li><input class="regular-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" name="group[13][2]" id="mce-group[13]-13-1" />
<label for="mce-group[13]-13-1"> Gigs &
Events</label></li>
<li>
<input class="regular-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" name="group[13][4]" id="mce-group[13]-13-2" />
<label for="mce-group[13]-13-2">Latest TB News</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Confused if that's a web standard however as the default code from Mailchimp don't use that in their naked embed code! Added them but still no luck in safari. What did you mean by form control?  Adding a default class to <input class=""> to control sizing?

Comment: UPDATE: added default form control classes to <input> and closed tags with shorthand /> but still not rendering in Safari! Oddly the /> doesn't appear to be in the markup for Chrome after update, implying that it's not required? <input> is simply not rendering in in Safari as per the screenshots above :s

Comment: weird because I run the code snippet on your original code I can see the the form next to the email* and I'm using safari on my Mac.  form-control is a boot strap class. if you running your project on apache tomcat you can use your iphone (yourmachinelocalip:8080/yourprojectfolder)to brows and see it it happened to safari on your phone too or may it your development machine only.